# How to catch Out of Gas exception in Oraclize Callback and display error on dapp front end

Tags: gas, dapps

I have a smart contract inside which I have used Oraclize to get current time stamp. On few occasions the Oraclize callback fails due to out of Gas exception. How can one catch this failure and display error message on my dapp front end?

I tried below options :

1. Monitor an event to catch if Oraclize returns any value or not. In my case it returns the current time stamp and moves ahead to logic inside the callback function. So here I could not catch the exception.
2. Monitor a second event which is triggered when computations using the timestamp returned by Oraclize are complete. Here also I am unable to catch the exception as it runs out of gas before reaching the logic to trigger the success event.

As per my understanding the out of gas exception happens in between the above two events i.e. after sending value and before completing the processing it looses all the gas.

Please help to suggest what is the preferred way to handle this error and communicate to user on the frond end.

Comment: If the transaction fails none of the events will be triggered.

Comment: then what is the ideal way to inform a user about it on the front end?

Comment: can you show me the oraclize transaction that fails, in etherscan?

Comment: sorry but I am testing locally using Ganache. Below is error message : }
[2018-08-17T11:55:47.960Z] INFO sending __callback tx...
        {
    "contract_myid": "0x58a88cebdf576344bff17f2caa61d373f7a3beb619f71538a6e58dbd017405d1",
    "contract_address": "0x98d9f9e8debd4a632682ba207670d2a5acd3c489"
}
[2018-08-17T11:55:48.643Z] ERROR callback tx error, contract myid: 0x58a88cebdf576344bff17f2caa61d373f7a3beb619f71538a6e58dbd017405d1
        {
    "message": "VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas",

Comment: I do not understand, what fails? the oraclize transaction to your contract? if so, how are you testing this locally?.

Comment: from the oraclize callback function I call another function whose job is to store data inside mappings in the smart contract. Oraclize does returns timestamp perfectly but it is during the execution of extra logic inside the callback function it ends up exhausting all the gas before completion.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to this is to set in your app as compulsory gas amount the minimum that is necessary to run the function without running out of gas.

Also, If the call fails you can just check for transactions to your contract on each block. Identify which one is from oraclize and check if it failed or not.

Hope this helps

Comment: I did read about computing gas amount before calling the function but could not find any sample code which does so, would you be able to provide some references that I can use ?